# Joomla Auto Dealer Inventory Website?

Tags: joomla

Hi are there any good Joomla extensions or pre made website to use as an inventory auto dealer site?

Comment: did you have a look at the Joomla Extensions Directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RD Autos is a pretty decent extension, but it is developed by a European so it has a Euro bent to it, which means some of the fields they use are not used by American and there are some fields missing that are widely used by Americans. We use it on a couple of sites but it's been heavily modified to fit American dealer needs.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/vertical-markets/vehicles/5458

K2 would also be a really good choice. You can define what ever extra fields you need to use then make a car detail subtemplate to display any way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking in the Joomla extensions library - [here](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/vertical-markets/vehicles)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like K2 http://getk2.org/ or Flexicontent http://www.flexicontent.org/ to create a catalogue if that's what you mean?